# Using the dollar alias for JQuery with selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am using selenium addon as well as jquery in my addon. Due to use of jquery functions with $ being used in selenium  throwing function not found error. Removing the Jquery, everything works fine. Using Jquery (ajax call) is must for me. Please suggest how can I make them work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One [recommended way](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) to solve this kind of conflict is to wrap your javascript code inside a function, and pass `jQuery` as an argument to this function :

```
// e.g : turn this code :
$(function(){
    $('.my-class').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax(...);
    });

    ...
});

// into :
(function($) {  // start an anonymous function,
                // whose first argument is named '$' ...

    $(function(){
        $('.my-class').on('click', function(){
            $.ajax(...);
        });

        ...
    });

}(jQuery)); // and call this function right away,
            // passing the jQuery object as first argument
```

---

Note that `$` is just a shortcut for `jQuery` :

```
jQuery('.my-class') and jQuery.ajax(...)
// are exactly the same as :
$('.my-class') and jQuery.ajax(...)
```

You can also use your own alias :

```
var $j = jQuery;
```

If some day you need to mix `jQuery` with another library which defines a `$` variable, you can also use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) (example taken from [this use case](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)) :

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Error is not being thrown while calling jquery. Error occur during selenium function calls. I tried replacing $ with jquery. It didn't work. Actually I need a way so that $ in selenium not being recognised as Jquery.

Comment: jQuery.noConflict() is the way to go.